# how to know when checking a radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, icheck

I'm making an application that displays a radio buttons using `jQuery.icheck` when clicking on a certain div, i want to take a certain action when checking one of these buttons, i'm using the instructions listed in the icheck website but got nothing the code i'm using :

```
var itemoptions=[],optionstring='', oi=0;

for(oi=0;oi<=oc-1;oi++) {
  itemoptions[oi]=$('menu').find($(".selected").text()).children().eq(si).children().eq(oi).prop('nodeName');
  optionstring=optionstring+'<input type="radio" name="iCheck"><p style="line-height:10px; font-size:15px;">'+(itemoptions[oi]).toString()+'</p>'
}

$('.item_block').on('click',function(){
$('input').iCheck('check');    // here's the line of code that is supposed to be used to check all of he icheck radio buttons 
$(this).addClass('flipped_item');
  $(this).flip({                              //flipping options
  direction:'lr',
  speed:250,
  content:"<div class='option_wrapper'>"+optionstring+"</div>",
  onEnd:function(){$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-yellow',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-yellow'
  });
})
```

Comment: Look under callbacks http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/#demo

Comment: Bit confused on the question. You bind an event or do you want to change something about the buttons? What exactly is the problem, and what have you tried. Also a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with a markup example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use

document.getElementById("check1").checked=true

statement

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, and you simply want to perform an action when that radio button is checked or unchecked, you can bind it to a change event.

```
$(this).flip({                         //flipping options
    direction:  'lr',
    speed:      250,
    content:    "<div class='option_wrapper'>"+optionstring+"</div>",
    onEnd:      function() {
                    $('input').iCheck({
                        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-yellow',
                        radioClass: 'iradio_flat-yellow'
                    });
                    $('input').change(function() {
                        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                            // Do Stuff
                        else
                            // Do other stuff
                    });
                }
});
```

Comment: doesn't give me any response

Comment: Your problem may be that you're invoking certain statements (like the .change or .iCheck) before your radio buttons are actually appended to the DOM. I'm not familiar with what this flip function does, but I'm assuming that's what the onEnd represents. See if my updated answer works.